# Mysql - inner join with or condition taking long time mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help with MySQL query.

I have indexed mandatory columns but still getting results in 160 seconds.

I know I have a problem with Contact conditions without it results are coming in 15s.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

My Query is :

```
 SELECT `order`.invoicenumber, `order`.lastupdated_by AS processed_by, `order`.lastupdated_date AS LastUpdated_date, 
    `trans`.transaction_id AS trans_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`trans`.subscription_id) AS subscription_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`trans`.price) AS trans_price, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`trans`.quantity) AS prod_quantity, 
    `user`.id AS id, `user`.businessname AS businessname, 
    `user`.given_name AS given_name, `user`.surname AS surname
    FROM cdp_order_transaction_master AS `order` 
    INNER JOIN `cdp_order_transaction_detail` AS trans ON `order`.transaction_id=trans.transaction_id 
    INNER JOIN cdp_user AS user ON (`order`.user_id=user.id OR CONCAT( user.id , '_CDP' ) = `order`.lastupdated_by)
    WHERE `order`.xero_invoice_status='Completed' AND `order`.order_date > '2021-01-01' 
    GROUP BY `order`.transaction_id 
    ORDER BY `order`.lastupdated_date 
    DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: When query is very slow. Don't use `ORDER`. It is speead eater. This is first point. For more detail, you have to give samples of the tables.

Comment: When you ask about query optimization you must provide complete CREATE TABLE for all tables and EXPLAIN for the query. At least...

Comment: Hi @Deepaksaini please change position in where clause like date first and status. As you've used inner join so where clause condition can move to on clause. And Use a subquery for cdp_user where you can handle concat operation.

Comment: Your query is logically incorrect. Simply enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and ensure. Adjust GROUP BY expression.

Comment: @RahulBiswas *As you've used inner join so where clause condition can move to on clause.* Makes no sense. Read Reference Manual about JOIN and WHERE optimizations - it tells that all conditions are extracted from ON clause and are processed like you use cartesian with these conditions in WHERE.

Comment: Hi @Akina For optimization it is necessary to extract only required data from large volume of data. ex. select * from tran inner join tran_details ON id = id and trandate > ? AND status = ? then use another join.

Comment: @RahulBiswas Do you think that moving the condition from WHERE to ON can change anything in the query with INNER JOIN? no, this is not correct, the execution plans will be absolutely identical.

Comment: The `OR` in the `ON` condition is killing performance.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Index the columns used in the join, where section so that sql does not scan the entire table and only scans the desired columns. A full scan of the table works extremely badly.

create index for `cdp_order_transaction_master` table :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_order_transaction_master_transaction_id ON cdp_order_transaction_master(transaction_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_order_transaction_master_user_id ON cdp_order_transaction_master(user_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_order_transaction_master_lastupdated_by ON cdp_order_transaction_master(lastupdated_by);
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_order_transaction_master_xero_invoice_status ON cdp_order_transaction_master(xero_invoice_status);
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_order_transaction_master_order_date ON cdp_order_transaction_master(order_date);
```

---

create index for `cdp_order_transaction_detail` table :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_order_transaction_detail_transaction_id ON cdp_order_transaction_detail(transaction_id);
```

---

create index for `cdp_user` table :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cdp_user_id ON cdp_user(id);
```

**2.** Use Owner/Schema Name
If the owner name is not specified, the SQL Server engine tries to find it in all schemas to find the object.